# Is it OK if your pressed ginger juice has a pancake batter like consistency?

Tags: ginger

I pressed ginger yesterday and I put it in the fridge on the door, and this morning, the consistency was in the consistency of pancake batter. I have no Idea if this is okay or not. I don't know if it was ruined somehow or if it's still good.

Comment: Welcome to SA!  Want to share exactly the steps you took?  I mean, the ginger juice is probably fine, but we can help you figure out what happened if you offer more detail, or even a photo.

Comment: Is it foamy? If so, that might mean it has started to ferment.